# layout doesn't work when adding nodes to graph dynamically

Tags: cytoscape.js

When I add nodes to the graph statically via the elements property of

```
    $('#cy').cytoscape(..)
```

the layout option works but when I add them via

```
    cy.add({..})
```

the layout is ignored. I can apply new layout only on these events(click, mouseover, mouseout) like this:

```
    cy.on('mouseover', function(event) {
    cy.layout({name: "grid"});          
    });
```

and the layout changes. Tried with other events: ready, done and load but it doesn't work.

Is there a normal way way to change the layout when elements are added dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a second layout while the initialisation layout is running.  Configure your initialisation properly (http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/initialisation) to have all the data and options you require.

As for `cy.add()`: Don't try using `cy.add()` on load unless you specify everything you need (incl. position) for those elements.  Or, you'll have to at least wait for `layoutstop` before running a new layout.  In general, you're better off using the initialisation options to do things for you rather than having to worry about edge cases and event synchronising yourself.